# Match dynamic string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to detect an occurrence of a string within string. But the code below always returns "null". Obviously something went wrong, but since I'm a newbie, I can't spot it. I'm expecting that the code returns "true" instead of "null"

```
var searchStr = 'width'; 
var strRegExPattern = '/'+searchStr+'\b/'; 
"32:width: 900px;".match(new RegExp(strRegExPattern,'g'));
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Please don't put '/' when you pass string in RegExp option

Following would be fine

```
var strRegExPattern = '\\b'+searchStr+'\\b'; 
"32:width: 900px;".match(new RegExp(strRegExPattern,'g'));
```

Comment: could you try with searchStr only without `\\b` part? your string supposed to work without that.

Comment: @Fares, you need `'\\b'` with 2 '\'s, not `'\b'`.

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing up the two ways of creating regexes in JavaScript.  If you use a regex literal, `/` is the regex delimiter, the `g` modifier immediately follows the closing delimiter, and `\b` is the escape sequence for a word boundary:

```
var regex = /width\b/g;
```

If you create it in the form of a string literal for the RegExp constructor, you leave off the regex delimiters, you pass modifiers in the form of a second string argument, and you have to double the backslashes in regex escape sequences:

```
var regex = new RegExp('width\\b', 'g');
```

The way you're doing it, the `\b` is being converted to a backspace character before it reaches the regex compiler; you have to escape the backslash to get it past JavaScript's string-literal escape-sequence processing.  Or use a regex literal.

Answer (score 3):

The right tool for this job is not regex, but String.indexOf:

```
var str = '32:width: 900px;',
    search = 'width',
    isInString = !(str.indexOf(search) == -1); 

// isInString will be a boolean. true in this case
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: not it is wrong because the following sentence is also true: 
    var str = '32:width: 900px;',
    search = 'wid',
    isInString = !(str.indexOf(search) == -1);
    console.log(isInString);

Answer (score 1):

Notice that '\\b' is a single slash in a string followed by the letter 'b', '\b' is the escape code `\b`, which doesn't exist, and collapses to 'b'.

Also consider escaping metacharacters in the string if you intend them to only match their literal values.

```
var string = 'width';
var quotemeta_string = string.replace(/[^$\[\]+*?.(){}\\|]/g, '\\$1'); // escape meta chars
var pattern = quotemeta_string + '\\b';
var re = new RegExp(pattern);
var bool_match = re.test(input); // just test whether matches
var list_matches = input.match(re); // get captured results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **back tick** symbol to make your string dynamic **"`"**.

```
var colName = 'Col1';
var result = strTest.match(`xxxxxxx${colName}`);
```

by injecting `${colName}` in to the text, it can be editable dynamically.