# Does any middleware conflict with javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, laravel, d3.js

I'm having trouble getting a regular expression to work in my Laravel application using Javascript.

Here is a code snippet.  I'm trying to filter data by pulling records that match the submitted Year.  I'm using daily closing prices for a certain asset and want to only pull the data that begins with YYYY year in the date column with 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format:

```
d.forEach(function(data){
    dateCompare = new RegExp(year + "-" + /\d\d/ + "-" + /\d\d/ + " " + /\d\d/ + ":" + /\d\d/ + ":" + /\d\d/);

    console.log(data.date.match(dateCompare));

    if(d.date.match(year + "-" + /\d\d/ + "-" + /\d\d/ + " " + /\d\d/ + ":" + /\d\d/ + ":" + /\d\d/)){
        console.log("Match");
    }
    else{
        console.log("No match");
    }
});
```

The csv format, once again, looks as such:

```
date, close
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, 123.45     //year-month-day hour:minute:seconds
```

I can get the strings to compare together but it seems that it's not recognizing the Regex.  Console.log will print both strings being compared and it prints them both, one as a literal regex string and the other as a simple date format string.

Currently, I don't have it set to do anything other than console.log a result.  I've tried multiple if-statement formats including `if(... === true)`, `if(...)`, etc. and the function continues to print only "No match" even though it comes across date formats that should align with my regex.  I've also tried storing the regex as a string and also just comparing it directly to a Regex object.  Still no success.

I followed a bunch of different guides that all said the same thing and tried to implement it both implicitly and explicitly and the results were the same.  Am I doing something wrong with Regex?

App is built on top of Laravel but I don't have problems running any other scripts in my script files so I don't see why this should be an issue either?

Edit:  Code snippet left out the declaration of optional function parameter `year` which defaults to 2010 in the event of no parameter.  It seems my only problem is matching the strings together and that my web app cannot compare a Regex string to the `.date` attribute of `data`.  Or maybe it is but my implementation is wrong.  I'll tinker some more and see if I can get it to work.

Also forgot to mention that I'm using the `d3.js` library.

`d` is a variable containing the raw data output from reading the `.csv` file and `data` is the variable being passed into the local scope of `function(data)`.

Comment: Take a look at [Match dynamic string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145073/match-dynamic-string-using-regex) and maybe this [MDN String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

middleware conflict with javascript regex?

> No

where did data.date come from?
I think you can try to compare them in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I'm passing `data`, which is the output of reading a `.csv` file and it passes the correct value into the function.  Then the function iterates through the object and compares each `data` attribute `.date` to a regex string that should match the year + any string of digits that follow in a y-m-d h:m:s format.  I can get the object to be passed into the function but the problem arises when I compare the strings.  It always `console.log`s 'No Match'.

Comment: I suppose I could compare the strings on the back-end and use AJAX to asynchronously update the charts.  The ultimate goal is to make the chart update without a page refresh since I will seemingly have a lot of different chart options and I want it to be manipulated quickly and seamlessly.  

If I can't get JS regex to work on string comparison, I might have to change it around but someone else above me posted a link that shows a slightly different syntax for JS regex than I had seen in my google searches so I might have to give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
d.forEach(function(data){
   dateCompare = new RegExp(year + "-" + '\\d\\d' + "-" + '\\d\\d' + " " + '\\d\\d' + ":" + '\\d\\d' + ":" + '\\d\\d');

   if(data.date.match(dateCompare)){
      console.log("Match!!!!!!");
      array.push(data)
   }
   else{
      console.log("No match");
   }

});
```

This works.  Thanks for the link iljubadr.