# converting array to regex, not working in match function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a lengthy array of location names.  I am trying to build a command which, when a phrase is typed into a text box, I can parse the phrase text to determine if any of the locations in my list are mentioned.  I have done this successfully with a regex containing a small group of strings which I created manually, but with this array conversion I only get "undefined" as an outcome.  My working function (created manually) is shown below, followed by the one I am struggling with.  I think this is due to the structure of the RegEx somehow (maybe it needs brackets?) but I can work out how to find the issue.  Any help in troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated

working code with manually created regex strings.  Note, "readCommandText" is a function I created to read the text to be checked

```
let colorSet = /\b(red|green|blue)\b/; 

function matchRobot() {
    let text = readCommandText(true);
    let result = text.match(colorSet);
    console.log(`color: ${result[1]}`)
 }
```

Non working code with array conversion (actual list of locations is much longer).  No matter what location I input I still see "undefined"

What am I overlooking?

```
locationArr = [brisbane, paris, london, singapore, dubai, seattle];
let locations = new RegExp(locationArr.join("|"), "gi");

function matchLoc() {
    let text = readCommandText(true);
    let result = text.match(locations);
    console.log(`location: ${result[1]}`)
 }
```

Comment: I think you should look at your variable names, you are joining the array `landmarkArr` which i don't see. Then inside the match method you use a variable called `landmarks` which is also no where to be found.

Comment: Did you mean to write `locationArr = ["brisbane", "paris", "london", "singapore", "dubai", "seattle"];` and then `let locations = new RegExp("\\b(" + locationArr.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");`?

Comment: There is so much wrong with it, that I really recommend you to get an editor like Visual Studio Code, which tells you about some common mistakes, like using variables that dont exist

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - it was just a typo when writing my question, the code itself has the correct variables, appreciate you checking rather than assuming :)  I have edited to correct the typo and Mara below has answered with your comment.  Thanks again

Comment: Then it is a duplicate of [Match dynamic string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145073/match-dynamic-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this, I used a phrase to mock the text from `readCommandText(true)`; As Wiktor suggested, you can compose your regex like this:

```
new RegExp("\\b(" + locationArr.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");
```

```js
const locationArr = ["brisbane", "paris", "london", "singapore", "dubai", "seattle"];
let locationsRegXp = new RegExp("\\b(" + locationArr.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");
console.log(locationsRegXp)

function matchLoc() {
  let text = "I wanted to travel to seattle and london this year but 2020.."
  let result = text.match(locationsRegXp);
  console.log("location: " + result)
}

matchLoc();
```

Comment: Thanks Mara!  I have no idea why this got downvoted, this was exactly what I was missing - how to add the boundary - really appreciate it :)